# Is there a way to replay videos/image on google meet or zoom?

Tags: video, meetings

So instead of sending the video feed a video or image is played/showed in a loop and everone sees only the video or image looping?
[pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZk2X.png)

Comment: Are you wanting to force people to only see that, as the primary screen in the Meet or Zoom they're viewing, or just as the image they see of you?

Comment: Only what they see of me.

Comment: Have you searched online, because I was able to find several guides from prominent and reputable sources for doing this. Basically, you need to set you "background image" to what you want, and then tape over or cover your camera so all that is seen is the background image. Note, if you are in school or a professional situation this will not be appropriate and you should not do it in these situations.

Comment: @music2myear, thanks for the info, Im well aware of sittuation and this is strictly personal not professional, but thanks.